# Openstack : fail to bind port when creating an instance

Tags: shell, configuration, cloud, openstack

I'm deploying openstack on 3 nodes (controller, compute and block storage).

I have installed : keystone, nova, neutron, placement, glance, cinder and horizon with the Victoria's guides.

When I try to create an instance with

```
openstack server create --flavor m1.nano --image cirros   --nic net-id=92dc8bf4-30be-4fdb-a1f4-bc91126dbc38 --security-group default --key-name demokey provider-instance
```

I get in /etc/neutron/server.log (on controller node) :

```
ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-3114ffac-2825-4db6-8586-0b3685fa6b1d b21b8901642c470b8f668965997c7922 0f23d567d2ce4599a1571d8fd5982f9a - default default] Failed to bind port 66f23e36-a360-444c-a3f7-2f7a904037dd on host compute1 for vnic_type normal using segments [{'id': 'e238d39a-ec1a-447a-a272-19cf4e4f76e1', 'network_type': 'flat', 'physical_network': 'provider', 'segmentation_id': None, 'network_id': 'd4c8fb07-7e56-4768-b725-93f3b97e1772'}]
```

I feel like linuxbridge fails to bind ports on compute node.

`ip a` on controller returns (looks like binding is done)

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:2f:4a:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42a8:f0ff:fe2f:4a6c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master brq92dc8bf4-30 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:2f:4a:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::42a8:f0ff:fe2f:4a6d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:2f:4a:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:2f:4a:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: tap0d0faf0c-99@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brq92dc8bf4-30 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:55:51:ff:a9:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns qdhcp-92dc8bf4-30be-4fdb-a1f4-bc91126dbc38
7: brq92dc8bf4-30: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:2f:4a:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.20/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global brq92dc8bf4-30
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::14dc:8eff:fe27:996d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But on compute `ip a` returns (no binding) :

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:18:82:78:cd:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.3/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9618:82ff:fe78:cd5c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:18:82:78:cd:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.30/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9618:82ff:fe78:cd5d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:18:82:78:cd:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:18:82:78:cd:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Also on controller `ip netns` return a qdhcp namespace while nothing on compute.

`brctl show` return a bridge on controller while nothing on compute.

Configs files are coherents and same as in the tutorials. I'm a bit loss. Do you have a clue where I need to dig ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Check the linuxbridge agent log on the compute node.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, there is nothing there, except some security group member updates...

Same for the neutron-linuxbridge-agent.log on the controller.

Comment: Looking at the server start command, it seems you are attaching the instance to the external network. Is that correct? Do you have tenant networks in this cloud? If so, can you launch instances on tenant networks? Often, only an admin user can launch instances on the external network; I wonder if that might be the case here.

Comment: I used the openstack guides to get started. Each of my nodes have 2 attachements eno1 on the management network and eno2 on a provider network (192.168.3.0/24).

I'm trying to attach an instance to this physical network, to do so I defined the network in openstack (called provider and subnet is called also provider 192.168.3.0/24) it appears to be active. 

I tried with the admin credentials and a suitable keypair, but I get same error.

Comment: In /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini in the [inuxbridge_agent] section I set "physical_interface_mappings = provider:eno2" on compute node.

Answer (score 0):

`nova boot --flavor m1.tiny --image cirros-0.3.5 --nic net-name=demo-net --availability-zone=nova:testcom1 testvm1`

I have same issue when create VM by command above

After a time, I found out the reason is my `net-name=**demo-net**` set wrong `provider:physical_network` value. My physical was set is not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, finally in my case it turned out to be the version of neutron that was inconsistent with the versions of other openstack components...